# How to choose between empty values or NULLs in a Django model with a UniqueConstraint based on two fields where one of them is optional?

Tags: python, django, unique-constraint

I have a Django model with a Uniqueconstraint based on two fields values, one of them is mandatory the latter being optional.

What is the best pratice here for the "optional" field (and why) to store "no value" between:

1. No value = empty
2. No value = NULL

**models.py**

```
class Foos(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    # Optional field
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'foos'

    def __str__(self):
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'alias'], name='unique_foo')]
        object_name = self.name
        return object_name
```

Note that I need to insert a bunch of values from an external source file, value for 'alias' could be equals to None.

Addendum: In fact, data can be inserted in two ways, from a form and from an Excel file. Form-based insert goes as below, so I ended up with field alias having empty values and NULLs which is annoying from the constraint perspective which need to be enforced if alias is NULL or empty, that why I'm asking for "best practice" here.

**forms.py**

```
class FooCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))
        self.fields['alias'] = forms.CharField(label='Alias',required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))

    class Meta(object):
        model = Foos
        fields = ('name','alias')
        
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        return name
        
    def clean_alias(self):
        alias = self.cleaned_data['alias']
        return alias
```

**my_importer.py**

```
# Only relevant code mentionned

foos_imported = []

for foo in foos:
    foo_name = foo["Name"]
    
    if not Foos.objects.filter(name=foo_name,alias=foo["Alias"]):
        foo_obj = Foos(
                          name=foo["Name"],
                          alias=foo["Alias"],
                      )
        
        try:
          foo_obj.save()
          foos_imported.append(foo)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Can't create foo {} : {}".format(foo["Name"],e.args))    
                
    else:
        logger.warning("Foo \"{}\" already exists within database, it won't be imported".format(foo_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple Foos with `name="a"` and `alias=None`. but you can only have one `name="a"` and `alias=""` pair.

Comment: I updated my question because it was lacking important elements for my use case.